# Facebook Javascript SDK difference between these events?

Tags: javascript, facebook, coffeescript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to figure out what the difference between these events are. They appear to behave differently between a local sinatra server and one deployed to heroku. They generally just behave differently between any localhost vs actual deployment. if anyone could she some light on this so I don't have to keep fiddling with it.

```
FB.Event.unsubscribe ('auth.authResponseChange') , @oAuthVars
FB.Event.unsubscribe ('auth.statusChange' ) , @oAuthVars
```

(this is in coffee)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The difference between these two events is that auth.authResponseChange is fired when the information about the current session changes, and auth.statusChange is fired when the session itself changes. So, for example, when a user logs in or logs out, statusChange is fired. If something about the session itself changes, like maybe the expiresIn time, the auth.authResponseChange event is fired.

Comment: If i was in connected status, and the connected facebook users on the browser got replaced but they are both connected and then i'm refetching the  session status (FB.getLoginStatus) with the forced round trip to the server. which events i'll get?